# Creating a text input that brings up the numeric keyboard but does not format results

Tags: iphone, html

I'm working on a iPhone compatible web page.  I need to bring up the numeric keyboard but keep the field from formatting the input.  The input should be either three groups of numbers separated by a decimal point (##.##.##) or four groups of numbers separated by a decimal point (##.##.##.##).

```
type="number"
```

Formats the input so that only one period is allowed.

```
type="tel"
```

works on the iPad, but brings up the wrong keyboard on iPhone.

Sorry if this is an easy question, I'm new both to HTML 5 and iPhone development.